# Show that if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum (\tfrac{n+1}{n})a_n$ also converges absolutely.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)a_n$$ is also convergent.

Edit: Originally, I thought about doing a limit comparison test, where your $b_n$ would get $\frac{1}{n}$. Then that limit of $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{n^2}\right)$ would be 1. So the series turns is comparable to $a_n$. But it seems wrong to ignore $a_n$ when doing the limit comparison.

Edit 2: My mind doesn't function so the attempt of the above edit isn't good for the problem.

Comment: comparison test?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it would be weird to ignore $a_n$ wouldn't it?

Comment: Check out Abel's Criterion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test

Comment: Please provide some additional context to the question at hand, such as your attempt(s) and  basic knowledge or skill level surrounding the area of mathematics that this question covers. If you have made no attempt(s), then unfortunately, this question does **not** appear within the scope of *good questions* as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [***Help Center***](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) for Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

$$
\sum \left|(\frac{n+1}{n} ) a_n \right|
  = \sum \left| \left(\frac{1}{n} + 1\right) a_n\right|
  < \sum |a_n| + \sum |a_n|$$

both of which converge.

Comment: Did you compare $$\sum{\frac{a_n}{n}}< \sum{a_n}$$ If that's the case, isn't it wrong to compare by ignoring n in the denominator?

Comment: The statement should be valid because n is a positive value $\geq 1$ i didn't ignore i say $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$

Comment: Please set a good mark for a good answer

Answer (score 0):

ASssuming $a_n > 0$, you can do the following.

Comparison Test says if you have two series, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$, and $b_n < a_n$ for all $n$, then $\sum a_n < \infty \implies \sum b_n < \infty$.

It is easy to notice that for $n > 2$, we have $(n+1)/n^2 < 1$ hence $a_n (n+1)/n^2 < a_n$...

Comment: What if $a_n$ is not positive?

Comment: Let me edit my original question. We know $a_n$ is absolutely convergent, my bad.

Comment: @DavidMitra i suspected OP intended $a_n>0$, but did not explicitly write it in. Will add

Comment: So your $b_n$ is $\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right)a_n$? And you know that the limit of that approaches 0? So therefore if that's convergent, then $a_n$ must be convergent?

Comment: @bsafaria no limit comparison test, just regular one. Yes, pick $b_n$ as above then $b_n < a_n \implies \sum b_n < \sum a_n < \infty$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Comment: Sigh... I just realized I mistyped the question. The denominator is actually $n$. But would it be right to do: $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$ Because that approaches 1.

Comment: @bsafaria just note $$\frac{n+1}{n} = \frac1n + 1$$ and expand and simplify